# How can I know the concrete object type without using dynamic_cast<...>()

Tags: c++, c++14

I am using a composite design pattern and I want to clone my objects from my composite class. I tried to make a generic clone method in my component class, but when I try to send the concrete type of my object to the generic (template) method, 'typeof' and 'typeid' returns the abstract class type. So, when I try to use new typeof(object), I see the error

> "invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'Component'".

My compiler is MigGW 32 bits.

As I can't know the type of my object, I can't use dynamic_cast.

Am I using typeof/typeid wrongly or should I use other keyword to know the concrete object type?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

class Component
{
public:
    template <typename Tdest> typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<Tdest>::type>::type* clone() const
    {
        typedef typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<Tdest>::type>::type NO_POINTER_NOR_CV;
        return new typeof(NO_POINTER_NOR_CV)(*dynamic_cast<const NO_POINTER_NOR_CV*>(this));
    }

    virtual void manipulateComponents() = 0;
    virtual void add(Component* comp) = 0;

protected:
    std::vector<const Component*> _v;
};

class Leaf : public Component
{
    void manipulateComponents() override { return; }
    void add(Component* comp) override { return; }
};

class Composite : public Component
{
public:
    void manipulateComponents() override
    {
        for(auto component : _v)
        {
            std::cout << typeid(component).name() << std::endl; // print PK9Component
            component->clone<typeof(component)>();

            /* ... */
        }
    }

    void add(Component* comp) override { _v.push_back(comp); }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Component* l = new Leaf();
    Component* c = new Composite();
    Component* parent = new Composite();
    parent->add(l);
    parent->add(c);

    parent->manipulateComponents();
}
```

Comment: Your error message is from `new Composite();` which is not valid (as `Composite` is abstract) - please fix those compilation error in order to provide a proper [mcve] that shows your issue with `typeid`

Comment: `Component` doesn't (and shouldn't) know how to clone instances of subclasses. Just make `clone` pure virtual and let each subclass do its own cloning.

Comment: Why can't you use `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Probably not important here, but I would assume that all gcc derivatives have very similar frontends (i.e. digest similar C++ dialects and constructs). The difference is in the backends, i.e. what code they produce, and against which libraries they link. With this in mind the *version* number is likely more important than whether it's Mi**n**gw, a cygwin gcc or one on a linux box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not getting the details of the derived type using `typeid` since you are using it on a pointer. Dereference the pionter in the call to get the name of the derived type.

Change

```
std::cout << typeid(component).name() << std::endl; // print PK9Component
// PK9Component seems indicate that it is a pointer to a Component.
```

to

```
std::cout << typeid(*component).name() << std::endl;
//                  ^^
```

Comment: it works to print the expected type. But can I sent it as a template parameter?

Comment: No, you can't use it as a template parameter, both because typeid doesn't generate a type, and the dynamic type is known only at run time, not compile time.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a clone method, you have to add a virtual function to return it, as in:

```
struct A
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const = 0;

    A() = default;
    A(A const&) = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A const&) = default;

    virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : A
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const override
    {
        assert(typeid(*this) == typeid(B));
        return std::make_unique<B>(*this);
    }
};
```

The `assert` protects (at run time) against deriving from `B` w/o overriding the `clone()` method.

The C++ Committee is working on [A polymorphic value-type for C++](http://wg21.link/p0201), but that won't be available for a while.

Answer (score 0):

No amount of `typeof` magic in your clone method will give you the type of a subclass of a non-templated class. It can give you the type of an instantiated template, but the only possible instantiation of your clone method here is in your base class. Subclassing doesn't redefine template methods.

If you really want to, you can use template methods in subclassing if you're willing to use the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern". There's a sample [clone implementation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Polymorphic_copy_construction), which I'll quote here:

```
// Base class has a pure virtual function for cloning
class Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Shape() {};
    virtual Shape *clone() const = 0;
};
// This CRTP class implements clone() for Derived
template <typename Derived>
class Shape_CRTP : public Shape {
public:
    virtual Shape *clone() const {
        return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const&>(*this));
    }
};

// Nice macro which ensures correct CRTP usage
#define Derive_Shape_CRTP(Type) class Type: public Shape_CRTP<Type>

// Every derived class inherits from Shape_CRTP instead of Shape
Derive_Shape_CRTP(Square) {};
Derive_Shape_CRTP(Circle) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

With CRTP, you may do:

```
template <typename Derived>
class IClonable
{
public:
    virtual ~IClonable() = default;
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const {
        return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(cloneImpl());
    }
protected:
    virtual Derived* cloneImpl() const = 0;
};

template <typename Derived, typename Base>
class Clonable : public Base
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const { // Hide Base::clone to return static type.
        return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(static_cast<Derived*>(cloneImpl()));
    }
protected:
    Clonable* cloneImpl() const { return new Derived{static_cast<const Derived&>(*this)}; }
};
```

And then:

```
class Component : public IClonable<Component>
{
public:
    virtual void manipulateComponents() = 0;
    virtual void add(const Component&) = 0;
};

class Leaf : public Clonable<Leaf, Component>
{
public:
    void manipulateComponents() override {}
    void add(const Component&) override {}
};

class Composite : public Clonable<Composite, Component>
{
public:
    void manipulateComponents() override
    {
        for (const auto* component : _v)
        {
            auto cloned = component->clone(); // std::unique_ptr<Component>

            /* ... */
        }
    }

    void add(const Component& comp) override { _v.push_back(&comp); }
protected:
    std::vector<const Component*> _v;
};
```

With possible usage:

```
Leaf l;
Composite c;
auto parent = c.clone(); // std::unique_ptr<Composite>
parent->add(l);
parent->add(c);

parent->manipulateComponents();
```